# Does Docker Splunk logging driver support indexer ack

Tags: docker, splunk

Docker splunk driver is used in my application. Here is the configuration.

```
splunk-url: "https://splunk-server:8088"
splunk-token: "token-uuid"
splunk-index: "my_index"
```

My token of splunk have index acknowledgement enabled, such that Http Event Collector (HEC) requires X-Splunk-Request-Channel in header.

I am sure that event can be sent via a HTTP client like postman to HEC with the header, but I cannot find the configuration option from docker splunk driver to set it.

Given that splunk index ack is required by my organisation. Is there any workaround?
cheers